# Hi , I have a code from a website which moves a text from left to right. I want to stop and start the text by onmouse events

Tags: lightning, javascript-controller

In below code , a text is moving. I want to control this text with the help of onmouseover and onmouseout events. Can anyone guide?
Below is the code :

```
<aura:component implements = "force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="intervalId" type="Integer" default="0"/>
    <div id="parentDIV" style="overflow:hidden">
        <p style="position:relative;" id="tofloat">
            <b><span style="color:red" onmouseover = "{!c.pauseText}" onmouseout = "{!c.doInit}">Important Note : </span>
            I am Floating (Left to Right) Imformation...</b>
        </p>
    </div>
 </aura:component>
```

Controller :

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var lWidth = window.innerWidth ;//Get the window's width
        //The setInterval() method calls a function or 
        //evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
        window.setInterval($A.getCallback(function() { 
            helper.shiftDiv(component, event,lWidth);
        } ), 100);
    },
    pauseText : function(component, event, helper)
    {  
       var floatElement = document.getElementById('tofloat');    
        var changeposition = 20 ;
       floatElement.style = changeposition + px ;
        }

})
helper
({
    shiftDiv: function(component, event,lWidth) {
        var changeposition = component.get("v.intervalId");
        var floatElement = document.getElementById('tofloat');    
        if(changeposition < lWidth){
            floatElement.style.left = changeposition+'px';
            changeposition = changeposition + 5;
            component.set("v.intervalId",changeposition);

        }
        //reset the left to 0
        else{
            component.set("v.intervalId",0);
            floatElement.style.left = "0px";
            changeposition = component.get("v.intervalId");//resetting so as to hit the if block again
        }
    }
  })
```

Comment: No..I have new to this.. Could you please guide a bit

Comment: What exactly is your problem, though? Any errors? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with CSS, no JavaScript needed!

Example:

```
.THIS.animated:hover p {
    animation: 3s 1 normal rightToLeft;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
.THIS.animated p {
    animation: 3s 1 normal rightToLeft;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes rightToLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: 100%;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
}
```

---

```
<aura:component>
    <div class="animated">
    <p>Coming in from the right!</p>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

You can also gain greater control over the animation using the animationstart, animationstop, and animationiteration events for more precise control. The [MDN article on CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) has everything you need to get started.

This is actually preferable, as you'll get smoother, better performance on all devices.

Comment: HI @sfdcfox : Thanks , can you please let me know how can I move this text from left to right and will it work for anything what is in div including data coming from server ?

Comment: @MohitaKalra You can alter the from and to attributes of the keyframes to alter the behavior. And yes, you can include absolutely anything in there, as long as the wrapper component (here, a div) is hovered over, its contents will animate.

Comment: @sfdx : Yes that helped...Thank you